# How do I inject @WebServiceRef resources through Glassfish JNDI?

Tags: glassfish, jax-ws, jndi

My web application is a consumer of some internal web services provided by the organisation. I have seen a couple of examples where a web service reference is injected using something like:

```
@WebServiceRef(name="services/MyService")
MyService myService;
```

But I have no idea how to define the services/MyService JNDI object in Glassfish v3 such that it gets injected. I wish to define the webservice client class through the Glassfish administration and also specify the endpoint URL through the admin console. This way URLs are not hardcoded and easily managed.

Eventually I will also need to specify the username and password for HTTP authentication too in the same way apart from the URL. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a way to define a "global" JNDI name, but you can write a service-ref element in web.xml that will work:

```
<service-ref>
  <service-ref-name>services/MyService</service-ref-name>
  <service-interface>service.MyEndpointService</service-interface>
  <wsdl-file>http://example.com/MyWsdl</wsdl-file>
</service-ref>
```

You can then use the annotated field you mentioned.

For the username and password, once you get a proxy from the service, you can cast it to BindingProvider and then set properties:

```
MySEI proxy = myService.getMyEndpointPort();
BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider)proxy;
Map<String, Object> rc = bp.getRequestContext();
rc.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "myuser");
rc.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "mypass");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer to this long standing question. I guess using your method works. The username and password could also be part of the web.xml application context-param so that they're retrieved from the same place. Since we're putting it in web.xml, would it also work in Tomcat?

Comment: I have my doubts about it working in Tomcat since Tomcat doesn't implement JSR-109. Haven't tried it, though.

Comment: What about specifying the actual URL of the Endpoint? Ideally this is also configured through here. The URL in the WSDL bindings is sometimes not the actual URL of the web service endpoint you want to connect to.

Comment: I don't think you can configure a URL in the service-ref, but you could put that elsewhere in web.xml and then use the BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY to set it before you invoke the service.

Comment: You can't change the endpoint that is defined in the WSDL, but the WSDL you are pointing to can point to the server generated WSDL which would have the correct endpoint addresses